# Android: Can't load images previously taken with the camera

Tags: java, android, image

I can load stock images that came with the phone in the gallery.
But when I try loading an image from the camera directory (which is inside the same gallery), it doesn't show up.

But what's really weird is that it takes up the space as if the image was successfully loaded. So it takes up space, but it's invisible. (Confirmed this by giving the ImageView a black background that only appeared after loading an image from the camera directory.)

This is the permission I added to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
```

Here is the code used to load the image:

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) 
{
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}



 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try 
        {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) 
            {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVieww);
                Bitmap bitmapForImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);

                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmapForImage);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

This was taken from a tutorial.
If you'd like to try it yourself, it's only 1 class and 1 xml file:
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-php-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the bitmap was too large, and I had to scale it down.
This is the working code:

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try 
        {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) 
            {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVieww);

                Bitmap bitmapForImage = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile( imgDecodableString, 128, 128 );

                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmapForImage);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }



    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String imagePath,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```